# Adding custom attributes to HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html

I have been using data attributes to add custom attributes in HTML. Unfortunately data is not supported in older browsers.

As an alternative, what is the disadvantage of creating custom attributes in HTML?

As an example I created  `carType = 'nissa'` as an attribute in HTML, and I was able to parse it with javascript utilizing `element.getAttribute(attributename)`

It seems to work in every browser I have tested. What is the negative side to this workflow?

Comment: Can't you do that with data attributes as well? `data-carType = 'nissa'` then `element.getAttribute('data-carType')`

Comment: Consider using `data-*` attributes.  They are the standard way to add data to elements.

Comment: @Musa Capital letters are not allowed.

Comment: @Brad Why would they be not allowed?

Comment: @kapa Because the spec says so:  http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#custom-data-attribute

Comment: @Brad I see. But it also says: `All attribute names on HTML elements in HTML documents get ASCII-lowercased automatically, so the restriction on ASCII uppercase letters doesn't affect such documents.`

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032841/html5-custom-attributes-why-would-i-use-them http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992115/custom-attributes-yea-or-nay?rq=1 I don't know if it qualifies as a dupe?

Comment: @kapa I don't know about you, but I prefer my documents to remain compatible with XML.  It dosen't change the fact that capital elements aren't allowed... it's just that HTML parsers are nice to you.

Comment: @Brad Fine with that, I use them lowercased myself. Now we included every piece of information future visitors might find useful :).

Answer (score 3):

[`data-` attributes are supported even in older browsers.](http://caniuse.com/dataset) <sup>(see the Note)</sup>

You can simply get them using the way you described:

```
element.getAttribute('data-xy')
```

The negative side of using non-standard attributes is that they make your HTML invalid. Validation is a very useful tool for finding problems in your markup. If you use the [HTML5 doctype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Introduction_to_HTML5#Declaring_that_the_document_contains_HTML5_mark-up_with_the_HTML5_doctype) (you can safely do even in old browsers) using `data-` attributes will help you keep your markup valid.

[More information on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)